# Как добавить иконку font awesome 5 через css?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Не могу добавить иконку font awesome 5 через псевдоэлемент ::after

Вот код:

```
summary::after {
    content: "\f107";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так же как и 4.7, поменялся только `font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";` или `"Font Awesome 5 Brands";` ... др.:

```css
span,
strong{
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

span:before {
  content: "\f209";
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Brands";
  font-size: 5rem;
  color: #777;
}

strong:after {
  content: "\f13d";
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  font-size: 5rem;
  color: #777;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css">
  

  <span></span>
  
  <strong></strong>
```

Comment: Ваш метод хорош, но почему-то иконки из группы solid не ставятся, только brands. Мне нужно поставить стрелочку \f107

Comment: Спасибо большое все сработало1